# Programación Funcional en Racket, Lista, se pide incrementar en 100 cada elemento de una lista

Tags: c

Lo que he intentado, pero no lo consigo.

```
(define (incremento list )

  (cond
    ((null? list) 0)

     ((incremento ((+ 100) (car list))((cdr list))))
     (read)
   )
  )

(list 1 3 6)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

(define (Incremento Lista)
(cond
((null? Lista)empty)
(else (cons (+ 100 (car Lista))(Incremento (cdr Lista))))
)
)

Este es el codigo!